# NextJS get user agent from server and make it available across components and pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In our NextJS app we show specific content in a sidebar or in a popup depending on whether a user is on a mobile device or not.

We currently detect this via a useEffect() which allows us to use navigator/window.

However, this has a problem where, depending on what we default the page to (mobile/desktop) where the screen will render incorrectly for a split second before switching to the correct one (since the useEffect happens after page load).

I was thinking to have all pages have access to the userAgent that the server has so we can more intelligently default to mobile or desktop to avoid that split second layout change. Is there a proper way to do this in recent version of NextJS?

Comment: plase remove the `nestjs` tag from your question. That's another framework.

Comment: I would show initial screen based on screen width, and then after user agent load, show mobile/desktop